# Not able to insert AccountPartner through test class in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I was not able to insert mock data for AccountPartner through test class. I tried by inserting 2 accounts and one Partner object. Actually same code is working in case of running from Apex class or executing from developer console. Please see the below code and output and let me know solution..

```
@isTest
private class TestAccountPartner {
  private static testmethod void unittest(){

    test.startTest();
    Account sourceAccount = new Account();
    Account targetAccount = new Account();

    sourceAccount.AccountNumber='Number1';
    sourceAccount.Name='name1';

    targetAccount.AccountNumber='Number2';
    targetAccount.Name='name2';

    insert sourceAccount;
    insert targetAccount;

    Partner p = new Partner(AccountFromId=sourceAccount.ID, AccountToId=targetAccount.ID);

    insert p;

    Account sa = [select ID from Account where Name='name1'];
    Account ta = [select ID from Account where Name='name2'];
    System.debug('Source Account is: '+sa);
    System.debug('Target Account is: '+ta);

    List<Partner> partners = [select AccountFromId from partner];
    System.debug('Partner objects are: '+partners);

    List<AccountPartner> accountPartners = [select AccountFromId from AccountPartner];
    System.debug('account partners are: '+accountPartners);

    test.stopTest();
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
07:24:48:174 USER_DEBUG [26]|DEBUG|Source Account is: Account:{Id=00128000007YZk7AAG}
07:24:48:174 USER_DEBUG [27]|DEBUG|Target Account is: Account:{Id=00128000007YZk8AAG}
07:24:48:176 USER_DEBUG [30]|DEBUG|Partner objects are: (Partner:{AccountFromId=00128000007YZk7AAG, Id=00I28000000ZeBTEA0})
07:24:48:177 USER_DEBUG [33]|DEBUG|account partners are: ()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but I think this is because account partner is one of the special Role type relationships. Have you tried accessing the Target account's AccountPartner collection and using the add() method to add the Source account.

This isn't identical to your situation, but the solution has a similar example that is adding partners:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3805/how-to-update-account-object-when-related-accountpartner-is-updated-inserted-del